# Programming on an ARM tablet

Tags: c++, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, arm

Not sure whether to ask this here or on SuperUser... so please migrate it if required.

I was recently gifted an Asus Vivo WinRT tablet by my boss and I was looking forward to having a little portable testing environment.

Unfortunately, it contains an ARM processor and, as far as I can see, there are no development tools that will run on it. Everything is x86/x64.

Is there anything I can use to develop **on the actual tablet itself**? If not .NET, then perhaps a C and/or C++ compiler? SQL even? Anything? I'm having heaps of trouble finding anything myself.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not.  You'll need to use visual studio 2012 and create a windows store application.  From there you can build your app and side load it to the tablet.  There is a component you can install on rt that will enable you to debug the app as it runs on the tablet however, this comes with vs.

Most apps for any tablet are developed this way, as tablets usually less than ideal development machines.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I realize that the tablet isn't ideal.. but it is always on hand when I want to try something.. whereas a laptop/desktop isn't. Is there absolutely no option that you're aware of? I mean for any language.. not just .NET. I can't seem to find a compiler that is built for ARM for any language at all :(

Comment: I'm not aware of anything, no.  Someone would probably have to build one using winrt framework, I don't think compiling to arm would be enough.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead also, you could install vs on the surface pro tablet, I've done it.  But I'd still have to build against winrt to get an app to run on winrt / arm.

Answer (score 0):

The only way at the moment is to use remote desktop.  use the RDP client on the RT slate to connect to a PC with visual studio installed.